# How can I list files in a directory by modification date?

Tags: c++, file-management, readdir, dirent.h

Currently I'm using `readdir` and it is working fine. Now time has come where my folders are cluttered and searching through a list by alphabetical order (not guaranteed though, it's directory order) can be frustrating. So, how can I modify the code below to sort by modification date rather than it's current order?

```
static cell AMX_NATIVE_CALL n_dir_list( AMX* amx, cell* params)
{
    DIR *dir = (DIR*)params[1];

    struct dirent *ent;

    if ((ent = readdir (dir)) != NULL) 
    {
        cell *buf, *addr;

        amx_GetAddr(amx, params[3], &addr);

        switch (ent->d_type) 
        {
            case DT_REG:
                *addr = 2;
                break;
            case DT_DIR:
                *addr = 1;
                break;
            default:
                *addr = 0;
        }

        amx_GetAddr(amx, params[2], &buf);

        amx_SetString(buf, ent->d_name, 0, 0, params[4]);
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

The readdir function is from the dirent header, as follows:

```
static struct dirent *readdir(DIR *dirp)
{
   DWORD attr;
   if (dirp == NULL) {
      /* directory stream did not open */
      DIRENT_SET_ERRNO (EBADF);
      return NULL;
   }

   /* get next directory entry */
   if (dirp->cached != 0) {
      /* a valid directory entry already in memory */
      dirp->cached = 0;
   } else {
      /* get the next directory entry from stream */
      if (dirp->search_handle == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
         return NULL;
      }
      if (FindNextFileA (dirp->search_handle, &dirp->find_data) == FALSE) {
         /* the very last entry has been processed or an error occured */
         FindClose (dirp->search_handle);
         dirp->search_handle = INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE;
         return NULL;
      }
   }

   /* copy as a multibyte character string */
   DIRENT_STRNCPY ( dirp->curentry.d_name,
             dirp->find_data.cFileName,
             sizeof(dirp->curentry.d_name) );
   dirp->curentry.d_name[MAX_PATH] = '\0';

   /* compute the length of name */
   dirp->curentry.d_namlen = strlen (dirp->curentry.d_name);

   /* determine file type */
   attr = dirp->find_data.dwFileAttributes;
   if ((attr & FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DEVICE) != 0) {
      dirp->curentry.d_type = DT_CHR;
   } else if ((attr & FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY) != 0) {
      dirp->curentry.d_type = DT_DIR;
   } else {
      dirp->curentry.d_type = DT_REG;
   }
   return &dirp->curentry;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The Microsoft documentation for `FindNextFile` says, "If the data must be sorted, the application must do the ordering after obtaining all the results."  So if you want the directory sorted by modification date you'll have to read it all in and sort it yourself.